# The application of short-five lemma in the Hartshorne III 7.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, duality-theorems

[image]

I am not sure with the last step when it applies the short-five lemma, which suppose to be the commutative diagram 
[image]

In order to apply the 5-lemma, we will need to show in addition (1) $\text{Hom}(\mathscr{E}_0,\omega)\cong H^n(X,\mathscr{E}_0)'$ and (2) $\text{Hom}(\mathscr{E}_1,\omega)\to H^n(X,\mathscr{E}_1)'$ is an epimorphism.

My question is: Why both (1) and (2) are true? Thank you in advance for your answer. It will be the best if you can present the corresponding morphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know from the proof that (b) holds for any finite direct sum of $\mathcal{O}(q_i)$.

We also know that the $\mathcal{E}_i$ are such direct sums (notice there is a typo : Hartshorne forgot the word finite but it should be clear you can have it).

Thus (b) hold for the $\mathcal{E}_i$. But (b) tells you exactly that the maps $$Hom(\mathcal{E}_i,\omega) \rightarrow H^n(X,\mathcal{E}_i)'$$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: oh thanks, I just forgot he mentioned this fact earlier!!